# How do I get the most recently added object's Primary Key in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I don't know if there's something like this

```
`//context.Add(...) stuff...
var primaryKeyOfRecentObjectAddedToDB = context.SaveChanges();`
```

I just want the primary key the database gave to my most recently added object.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to it on your object, as soon as it is saved:

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }

context.Add(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
var id = foo.Id;
```

Better yet, use a Guid (instead of an identity column) for your id and you have access to it before you hit your database.

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }

var id = foo.Id; // have access to the id here

context.Add(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Isn't SaveChanges() the only method that accesses the database here (with an INSERT)? How is the first code snippet causing a round trip?

Comment: @NickB - SaveChanges will hit the database. In the first example the Id will not be available until you call SaveChanges. In the second method it is available *BEFORE* you call SaveChanges

Comment: So SaveChanges() does an INSERT and then retrieving the new Id of foo runs a SELECT somewhere in the background?

Comment: Without profiling EF I can't be sure, but I expect it defines an output parameter when doing the insert which is set to SCOPE_IDENTITY (the last identity value).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple entities of type `MyEntity` in the context which have to be inserted into the DB you could use something like this (in EF 4.1):

```cs
// save references to the entities which will be added in a local list
var listOfEntitiesToAdd = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
    .Select(e => e.Entity)
    .OfType<MyEntity>()
    .ToList();

// insert the entities, state will change to Unchanged,
// PK property (Id) gets populated
context.SaveChanges();

if (listOfEntitiesToAdd.Count > 0)
{
    // get highest created Id
    int maxId = listOfEntitiesToAdd.Max(e => e.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your primary key is a property of your entity and assigned by the DB it will be populated after you execute `SaveChanges()`:

```
context.Add(someFoo);
context.SaveChanges();
long myId = someFoo.Id;
```